# Two different reputations

Tags: bug, reputation, user-profile

[image: Reputation error]

In the above picture one can see that two different reputations are showing up in my profile one one the right side and another different on the graph. What is the error I can't understand. Please Help!

Comment: ...and the difference is the reputation you gained in the last 2 days?

Comment: This _might_ have something to do with your March 6 reputation incident. There is a similar report [My reputation graph on Math.SE shows me as having the wrong reputation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/254558) but it's marked completed. Perhaps it wasn't fixed completely. I'll retag this as a bug.

Comment: Maybe you should post this at meta.stackechange.com.